# Самое маленькое слово

Tags: c, c++

Есть текст, который построчно читается с файла. 
Нужно найти самые маленькие слова (именно слова, так как их может быть много), которые присутствуют в этом тексте. 
Можно на любом языке, я разберусь. Хотя бы маленький пример. 
Вообщем основной вопрос заключается в том, как найти эти слова?

---

Я читаю строки построчно с файла. Пусть найду самые маленькие слова в строке. Как их сохранить? Брать создавать динамический массив? 
Ок. Читаю вторую строку. Пусть в ней есть еще меньшие слова. Тогда как дальше? Освобождать память массива и заполнять его заново? 
Или может почитать весь файл целиком и работать со всем файлом одновременно? 
Какой оптимальный алгоритм можно составить?

Comment: За Вас вряд ли кто-то будет думать и решать Вашу задачу. Потому что в перспективе такой как Вы "программист" может стать в будущем коллегой и возникает вопрос: "Кому хочется работать с человеком, который даже не пытается решить проблему?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Пройтись первый раз по файлу и определить количество символов в самом маленьком слове.
2. Пройтись второй раз и записать слова подходящей длины в любую удобную структуру данных.

Answer (score 0):

На любом языке? Вот вам C#:

```
var allShortest = File.ReadLines(filename)
                      .SelectMany(l => l.Split())
                      .GroupBy(w => w.Length)
                      .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                      .First()
                      .AsEnumerable();
```

---

Более эффективный вариант:

```
int? minlen = null;
var allShortest = File.ReadLines(filename)
                      .SelectMany(l => l.Split())
                      .OrderBy(w => w.Length)
                      .TakeWhile(w => ((minlen = minlen ?? w.Length) == w.Length));
```

---

Двухпроходное решение:

```
var words = File.ReadLines(filename).SelectMany(l => l.Split());
var minlen = words.Select(w => w.Length).TakeUntil(l => l == 1).Min();
var allShortest = words.Where(w => w.Length = minlen);
```

Comment: А профайлером этот код? На какой-нибудь книге?

Comment: @alexlz: а где вы видите затык? `GroupBy` и `OrderBy` ленивые.

Comment: @alexlz: специально для вас, решение, не делающее лишнего.

Comment: @VladD это я по неграмотности. А OrderBy точно не требует считывания (со Split()) файла в память?

Comment: @alexlz: требует, но этого не избежать, самое короткое слово может быть и последним в файле.

Написал-таки двухпроходный вариант.

Comment: @VladD сравните. собирать (если не лень) `ghc --make v.hs` 

    import qualified Data.Set as S

    f (l, s) str | l == 0 || length str < l  = (length str, S.singleton str)
                 | length str == l           = (l, str `S.insert` s)
                 | otherwise                 = (l, s)

    main = do
      l <- (concatMap words . lines) `fmap` getContents
      let (len, s) = foldl f (0, S.empty) l
      putStrLn $ unwords $ S.toList s

Comment: @alexlz: у вас по идее должен быть больше расход по памяти: вы держите в памяти текущее множество-кандидат, а значит, если весь файл из двухбуквенных слов, а последнее однобуквенное, нагрузка на память не нужна. Двухпроходный вариант, кажется, более ленив.

---
У меня нет ghc, венда всё-таки :(

Comment: @VladD Насчёт того, что два прохода могут сэкономить память -- согласен. А вот насчёт "венды" -- непонятно. Посмотрите, какая часть разработчиков ghc трудоустроена в MS Research...

Так что http://www.haskell.org/platform/windows.html